# help with query that should only return most recent record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a simple view, that gets data from 2 databases.

I have a `booking` table that only shows each booking once and a diary table that is notes on each booking.

Each booking shows up multiple times in the diary table however I only want the most recent note and booking information in my view

For some reason this isn't working

```
SELECT     
    t0.BOOKNO, t0.PARTY, t0.TOUR, t0.DEPART, t0.DEP7, t0.BOOK7, t0.PAID, t0.APRICE, t1.TEXT
FROM         
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        TOP (100) PERCENT 
        dbo.DIARY.ADDED, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO, dbo.BOOKINGS.PARTY, 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR, dbo.BOOKINGS.DEPART, 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.DEP7, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOK7, dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID, 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE, dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS
     FROM          
        dbo.BOOKINGS 
     CROSS JOIN
        dbo.DIARY
     WHERE      
        (dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID IS NULL) 
        OR (dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID = 0)
     GROUP BY 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO, dbo.BOOKINGS.PARTY, dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR, dbo.BOOKINGS.DEPART, 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.DEP7, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED, dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE, dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS, 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOK7, dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID, dbo.DIARY.ADDED
     HAVING      
        (dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS <> 'xl') AND 
        (dbo.BOOKINGS.DEPART > CONVERT(int, GETDATE()))
     ORDER BY 
        dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO) AS t0 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT     
       BOOKNO, TEXT, MAX(ADDED) AS added
    FROM          
       dbo.DIARY AS DIARY_1
    GROUP BY BOOKNO, TEXT) AS t1 ON t0.BOOKNO = t1.BOOKNO
```

I tryed this but it didnt work unable to parse query text?

```
;WITH MostRecentBookings AS (  SELECT     dbo.DIARY.ADDED7, dbo.DIARY.ADDED, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO, dbo.BOOKINGS.PARTY, dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR, dbo.BOOKINGS.DEPART, 
                      dbo.BOOKINGS.DEP7, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED, dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOK7, dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID, dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE, dbo.BOOKINGS.STATUS, 
                      dbo.DIARY.TEXT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO ORDER BY dbo.DIARY.ADDED DESC) AS 'RowNum'  
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN   dbo.DIARY ON dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO = dbo.DIARY.BOOKNO 
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID IS NULL) OR     (dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID = 0)) 
SELECT    *  FROM    MostRecentBookings 
WHERE    RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain what's not working?  Does it give an error?  Or what wrong data is it returning?

Comment: the text column returns <unsopported type> for an odd reason and it should only be picking up 1 row per booking number but for some reason multiple are coming up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) combined with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to achieve this. Something like:

```
;WITH MostRecentBookings AS
(
   SELECT 
      (some columns),
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.BOOK_NO ORDER BY d.ADDED DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.Booking b
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Diary d ON ..........
)
SELECT
   (some columns)
FROM
   MostRecentBookings
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Basically, the CTE would do the join between the two tables, and it would then "partition" your data by `BOOK_NO` - this way, each unique booking gets a row number that starts at 1.

The numbering is such that the most recent entry gets number 1, and previous one gets subsequent higher numbers. From that CTE, select those entries with `RowNum = 1` for the list of the most recent bookings.

Comment: i tryed replicating what u did but it didnt work can u take a look

Comment: @bugz: seems OK that first glance - sorry, since I don't have your tables and don't see your screen, I really can't say why it wouldn't work...... try reducing the number of columns - just pick one from bookings and one from diary, and get that to work - then start adding more columns again. Also: could you post the **exact error message** you're getting??

Comment: them ulitpart identifier could not be bound for basically all my columns

Comment: @bugz: you should get used to using **table aliases** !  Use `FROM dbo.BOOKINGS b INNER JOIN dbo.DIARY d ON b.BOOKNO = d.BOOKNO` and use those `b.` and `d.` prefixes in your query, instead of constantly repeating the whole table names...

Comment: no but i am putting the database name ahead like a.dbo.bookings

Comment: The `dbo.` is **not** a database name - it's a **schema** name. You need to execute this when you're in the **right** database - otherwise you'll never get results